# Could I clone an SSD to another rig and start mining out-of-the-box on Rig B?

Tags: blockchain, backup

Hypothetically, could I just migrate the contents one SSD to another and mine on Rig B immediately? I found some information at https://radu.cotescu.com/migrating-your-ubuntu-machine-to-a-ssd-drive/

Will this work, assuming the size of the second SSD is same size or larger?

Comment: I did it using clonezilla. It works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, as long as everything in the `~/.ethereum` folder is transferred, your node should work just fine.

You actually don't even need to migrate anything, you can mine from any computer with a synced node just by setting the `coinbase` to your address. You'd need to resync the node if it's a new computer, though.